# Pawn promotion movement

Tags: rules, pawns, pawn-promotion

If a pawn is promoted, does that count as a move?  What if a rook is waiting and could capture the new queen in one move? What exactly happens when a pawn is promoted?

Answer (score 5):

The pawn promotion is part of the move of a white pawn to the eighth (or for a black pawn to the first) row. So you move the pawn to eighth row and replace it immediately with a piece of your choice (except kings, pawns or pieces of the opposite color). You don't need to spend an extra move for the promotion.

If a rook can immediately take your new queen, well such is life … ;-)
Maybe promoting wasn't such a good move then ...

Comment: … or maybe the move was still good, because you can capture the rook again. ;)